# Converting multiple summation into single summation

Tags: summation, summation-method

So I am working on a problem and I am required to convert multiple summations of the following form into a single summation,

\begin{align}
\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \alpha_{ijk} \,X^{i+j+k} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \beta_{n} \,X^{n}
\end{align}

So now I want to compare terms of the same powers of $X$ from both sides. Is there a nice way to convert the summations on LHS into a single summation? For this simple case it is easy to see that,

\begin{align}
\alpha_{000}&=\beta_0\\
\alpha_{100}+\alpha_{010}+\alpha_{001} &= \beta_1
\end{align}
and so on. But for some more complicated dependencies on $i,j,k$ in these summations and powers of $X$, it is not so straightforward to see this. Are there any techniques one can use? (Also for my problem differentiating both sides with $X$ is not an option.)

Any help is highly appreciated.